# sklearn - model.coef_ returns NxN matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
md    = dev_df['MD'].values.astype('float').reshape(1,-1)
tvdss = dev_df['TVDSS'].values.astype('float').reshape(1,-1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(md, tvdss)

f = model.predict(X)[0]

>>> model.coef_.shape
(78, 78)

>>> model.coef_
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])

>>> type(md)
numpy.ndarray

>>> type(tvdss)
numpy.ndarray
```

I have the above codes and I really don't understand why `model.coef_` is returning a matrix, instead of a single value. I expect it to be a single value like `0.3` or `13`, but its not.

Comment: What are the shapes of `md` and `tvdss`?

Comment: @Tomothy32 both (1, 78)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> **coef_ : array, shape (n_features, ) or (n_targets, n_features)**
>
> Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple targets are passed during the fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array
>   of shape (n_targets, n_features), while if only one target is passed,
>   this is a 1D array of length n_features.

You passed multiple targets, and therefore got a 2D array of shape `(n_targets, n_features)`.

Comment: I don't get what it means by I passed multiple targets. All I did was inputting X and Y for `model.fit(md, tvdss)`. Where did I pass multiple targets?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tvdss = dev_df['TVDSS'].values.astype('float')
```

and see what happens.

According to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit):

> y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)

In simple words, `y` must be a 1d vector, whereas you're passing a 1d column.